# Angular 2 complex logic to decide [style.background] not working

Tags: angular

I have very complex logic deciding which background image to display.

Here is how I'm attempting to accomplish it:

html:

```
   <div  class="form-control-icon"  
         id="switch-icon"
         [style.background]="imagePath">
   </div>
```

component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    @Component({
        selector: 'distance-units',
        templateUrl: 'app/find-page/distance-units.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['app/find-page/distance-units.component.css']
    })
    export class DistanceUnitsComponent {
       distanceUnit = "kilometers";
       isEnabled = false;
       isDisabled = true;
        imagePath = 'url("../images/switch-kilometers-disabled.png") center no-repeat';

        constructor() {
            this.imagePath = 'url("../images/switch-kilometers-disabled.png") center no-repeat';
        }

       toggleDistanceUnit() {
          this.distanceUnit =
             (this.distanceUnit === "kilometers" ? "miles" : "kilometers");
       }

       disableSelf() {

       }

        setImage() {
            this.imagePath = this.getImage();
        }

       getImage() {
            if (this.isEnabled) {
                if (this.distanceUnit === 'kilometers') {
                    return 'url(\'../images/switch-kilometers.png\') center no-repeat'
                } else {
                    return 'url(\'../images/switch-miles.png\') center no-repeat'
                }
            } else {
                if (this.distanceUnit === 'kilometers') {
                    return 'url(\'../images/switch-kilometers-disabled.png\') center no-repeat'
                } else {
                    return 'url(\'../images/switch-miles-disabled.png\') center no-repeat'
                }
            }
       }
    }
```

However, the actual control in the web page has no background property at all whilst running the web page. Initially the imagePath variable is set to what I thought was a valid value for the background css.

I do get this warning in the console but I don't see why that would cause the background to not be set:

> WARNING: sanitizing unsafe style value
>   url('../images/switch-kilometers.png') center no-repeat (see
>   http://g.co/ng/security#xss).

Can anyone see why the background property is not there?

Comment: have you considered instead of directly modifying the style, to add/remove a class? much more easily maintainable (and probably implementable.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work for you. Instead of putting `[style.background]` just do this:

```
[ngStyle]="{background: imagePath}"
```

The problem occurs because Angular 2 is "afraid" of the value you're trying to inject in to the DOM. Check this chapter on securing if you want to know more:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/security.html